# Editing listview control item

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, listview

How do you add or edit listview item by double clicking on it?

Comment: The absence of an `mfc` tag indicates that you're not using MFC. No reason to create useless new tags, even if they are slightly humorous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.  First, you have to create the List view control with the [LVS_EDITLABELS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774739%28VS.85%29.aspx) style, as shown in [Using List-View Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774736%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Then, when you want to edit the label, you send the [LVM_EDITLABEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774898%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) message to the focused label.

Be sure to handle the [LVN_ENDLABELEDIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774814%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) message in the parent.

Comment: Any ideas about adding an item on 'double click' when no item is selected?